# Add existing action_item to new member_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2 with Rails 4.2.1. In this resource I have `actions :all`. I've also defined a custom action item (those buttons on the top left):

```
action_item :my_action, only: [:show, :edit] { <SNIP> }
```

This works fine, in that the the button shows up on the show and edit pages. The button links to a custom member action:

```
member_action :my_action, method: :get { <SNIP> }
```

This creates a new route and page just fine, except that it has no action items. I'd like to link to the default edit and show pages in this custom page.

I tried `action_item :edit, only: [:show, :my_action]` hoping it would add `:my_action` to the default handler, but this errors with no block given. I'm worried that passing a block will override the default behavior (which is very close to what I want).